# Kendo UI dropDownList shows elements as undefined

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Great day to **Everyone**!

Recently I've started using KendoUI http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui in my project, and faced with the problem: let's say I want to create dropDownList and set simple 1D array as DataSource. When I do it at the moment of list creating - everything is fine:

```
 var temp = ["a", "b", "c"];
    $("#employee").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: temp,
    });
```

*screenshot:* http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0005/1191/378023/150916/4b863bff39.jpg
[image]

But if I want to just create empty dropDownList and only after any abstract event fill it with 1D array it leads to incorrect work: all elements are displayed as undefined. Once I pick one it turns to appropriate value.

```
var temp = ["a", "b", "c"];
    var employeeDropdownList = $("#employee").data("kendoDropDownList");
    employeeDropdownList.setDataSource(temp);
```

*screenshot:* http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/1191/378023/150916/0f311725b1.jpg
[image]
Probably that is because Kendo forces me to use "key: *key*, value: *value*" pattern for dataSource and I definitely don't want to do that. It keeps me frustrating that I can't simply set 1D array as DataSource at any time I want, not only at the moment of creation.

Hope for your help.

Comment: Those links are unreachable.

Comment: are they? That's strange. Anyway I've provided images

Comment: Seems to work fine in this dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/ADUti Can you edit it to reproduce the issue?

Comment: you may need to do a read() or fetch() on the ds after reassigning